# Android Studio : Fill a Listfragment from an activity

Tags: android

I have a fragment with a list fragment :

```
    public class F1_fr extends ListFragment {
   View rootview;



    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.f1_lay,container,false);
        final String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.heroes);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        setListAdapter(aa);


        rootview.findViewById(R.id.semi_transparent).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ajout.class);
               ;

               startActivity(intent);


            }
        });



        return rootview;

    }
```

and i use a button to go in another activity with a simple textfield and i want that the text i enter in the textfield is added to the listfragment

I think i need to use sqlite database to store data but i dont know how to say to my listfragment to add this String.    Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

may help to [read this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) and to consider MVC pricipals in Android...

MVC wise, your array "R.array.heroes" is the data ( a collection of model entries, typ=String ).

so when you start a new activity to add a text field to the list, think more in terms of your "add-new" activity as creating a new model and returning that model to the caller...

start the activity for a result and return the data or model that the caller can add to the data in the adapter....

start-NEW-MODEL-activity for result passing back the new STRING in the intent.

```
mActivity.getIntent().putExtra(ListActivity.EXTRA_MODEL, newStringObject);
mActivity.setResult(RESULT_OK, mActivity.getIntent());
finish();
```

in the caller, add the new model to the collection or the adapter's array....

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK  && EXTRA_ACTN_NEW_ITEM) {
    ((ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).insert(data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MODEL), 0);
```

Then call 'notify()' on the adapter if needed to refresh the list in the UI with the new list item.